# location data format for adehabitat package

Tags: r

I have a file in this format:

[ASCII format](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/ArcInfo+ASCII+Grid+format#ASCIIGrid)

The first rows look like this:

```
ncols 1440
nrows 720
xllcorner -180.0
yllcorner -90
cellsize 0.25
NODATA_value -9999
```

Basically I have the world with 1440 'tiles' in x direction (longitude) and 720 'tiles' in y direction (latitude). Each 'tile' is a square with a length of 0.25 degrees. I think I have xllcorner and yllcorner correct. I can draw this map like this in R:

```
library("adehabitat")
bio1 <- import.asc("D:/ENFA/data.asc")
maps <- as.kasc(list(data = bio1))
image(maps, col = cm.colors(256), clfac = list(Aspect = cl))
```

The map looks fine.

I would like to perform some ecological niche factor analysis (ENFA) using the adehabitat package and am not too sure about the location data. Basically I have them as longitudes and latitudes at the moment but I could also generate then as 'tile index' (e.g. lower left corner has the latitude -90 and longitude -180 so the 'tile index' would be 0, 0 - right?). Which is the correct location data format? I would use ENFA code like this:

```
locs <- read.table("D:/ENFA/Locs.txt", header = TRUE, sep="\t")
dataenfa1 <- data2enfa(maps, locs)
pc <- dudi.pca(dataenfa1$tab, scannf = FALSE)
enfa1 <- enfa(pc, dataenfa1$pr,scannf = FALSE)
hist(enfa1)
```

I would appreciate any comments please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with leaving your coordinates in lat-long form is that, at most places on earth, a degree of longitude has a different length than a degree of latitude. This might distort your ENFA by exaggerating distances in some directions relative to those in others.

Especially if your data are from a relatively small area, I'd suggest re-expressing the coordinates in meters along an W/E x-axis and S/N y-axis.  If all of your points fall inside a single [UTM zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system), then you could do the conversion within `R`, using `project()` in the `rgdal` package:

Here's one example, [taken from here](http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/converting-lat-long-points-to-UTM-td6075878.html):

```
library(rgdal)

# Make a two-column matrix, col1 = long, col2 = lat
xy <- cbind(c(118, 119), c(10, 50))
# Convert it to UTM coordinates (in units of meters)
project(xy, "+proj=utm +zone=51 ellps=WGS84")
          [,1]    [,2]
[1,] -48636.65 1109577
[2,] 213372.05 5546301
```

Much more info about how to manipulate spatial data is available in the "Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R" by Bivand, Pebesma, and Gomez-Rubio.  If you need more specific assistance, try the [R-sig-Geo mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-geo).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the book link. I've been meaning to get more into this field.

Comment: Thanks Josh. One problem with this is that the data can be from anywhere in the world (i.e. more than on of the 60 UTM longitude zones). Not sure what to do about that ...

Comment: Alternatively, you could do the conversion yourself.  A degree of latitude is 111 km. A degree of longitude is quite close to `cos(lat)*111`km, if `lat` is expressed in rads.  For lats in degrees, just use `cos(((2*pi)/360)*lat)*111` instead.  Try this out for a few latitudes, and compare to the values listed [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Degree_length]{in this Wikipedia article} to see that it works well.  This should work as long as your data sets don't extend over many degrees of latitude (or include large areas near the poles).  If this is useful, I'll add it to main response.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look into this.

Comment: @Josh - could you please correct this: "a degree of longitude has a different length than a degree of longitude" I would really like to understand this distortion stuff a bit better and the influence it may have on my analysis. Thanks!

Comment: @csetzkorn - Thanks for catching that.  The basic issue is that the length of a degree gets shorter and shorter as you move away from the equator. At the pole, you can walk through 360 degrees in a few steps; at the equator, it takes a 40,000 km journey to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to convert the coordinates into

> GHAM (Global, Hierarchical, Alphanumeric, and Morton-encoded)

which represents the globe by cells of arbitrary precision (as fine or coarse as you wish), so any lat/lon has a single alpha-numeric address that remains sortable.

Here's the abstract from [GHAM: A compact global geocode suitable for sorting](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cageo.2005.02.007), by [Duncan Agnew](http://igppweb.ucsd.edu/~agnew/):

> The GHAM code is a technique for labeling geographic locations based
>   on their positions. It defines addresses for equal-area cells bounded
>   by constant latitude and longitude, with arbitrarily fine precision.
>   The cell codes are defined by applying Morton ordering to a recursive
>   division into a 16 by 16 grid, with the resulting numbers encoded into
>   letter–number pairs. A lexical sort of lists of points so labeled will
>   bring near neighbors (usually) close together; tests on a variety of
>   global datasets show that in most cases the actual closest point is
>   adjacent in the list 50% of the time, and within 5 entries 80% of the
>   time.

Source code is the [IAMG](http://www.iamg.org/index.php/publisher/articleview/frmArticleID/108) repository, but if you can't access it I'm sure he would provide it.

Comment: Looks interesting but I don't think it is applicable in this context